# What is the order of execution of validations in DRF serializers?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am not able to understand the order in which validations on a serializer are executed.

Here is one of my serializer:

```
class InvoiceCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buyer_company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=CompanyModel.objects.filter(is_archived=False)
    )
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=OrderModel.objects.filter(
            is_archived=False
        )
    )
    shipping_address = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=AddressModel.objects.filter(
            address_type=ADDRESS_TYPE[1][0]
        )
    )

    def validate_buyer_company(self, buyer_company):
        # validation for buyer company
        return buyer_company

    def validate_shipping_address(self, shipping_address):
        # validtion for shipping address which require buyer company from request data
        return shipping_address

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # validations for extra fields

        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my Invoice Model:

```
class InvoiceModel(BaseModel):
    # relative fields
    buyer_company = models.ForeignKey(
        CompanyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='invoice_buyer_company'
    )
    seller_company = models.ForeignKey(
        CompanyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='invoice_seller_company'
    )
    seller_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(
        WarehouseModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='invoice_seller_warehouse'
    )
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(
        AddressModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='invoice_shipping_address'
    )
    ...
```

Now if buyer company is not present in my request data, it should raise a framework validation error for required field. but instead it keeps going on and as my validate_shipping_address requires buyer company, it gives a Key Error.
How to validate the required fields before hand and then execute the custom field validations?

Comment: kindly show your `models.py` file

Comment: i have added the model

Comment: I've added the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593896/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-validations-in-drf-serializers/63596084#63596084)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
class InvoiceCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buyer_company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=CompanyModel.objects.filter(is_archived=False)
    )

     def validate_buyer_company(self, buyer_company):
        created_count = CompanyModel.objects.filter(buyer_company=self.context['request'].id).count()
        min_count = 1
        if created_count < min_count :
            raise serializers.ValidationError("buyer company ID should present in Invoice data")
        return buyer_company


    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Alternet Method:**

```
from django.db.models import Q

class InvoiceCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        _id = data['id']
        queryset = InvoiceModel.objects.filter(Q(buyer_company__id__iexact=_id)).distinct()

        if not queryset.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("buyer company ID should present in Invoice data")
        return buyer_company
```

Comment: This seems to be a valid answer but what I want to know is why serializer is not raising field required error. Logically it  should check for that validation first then proceed